# API для получения информации о товарах от различных поставщиков — куда смотреть?

Tags: xml, парсер, api

Есть у меня идея сделать вебсервис связанный с интернет коммерцией - не могу понять как сделать так чтобы разнородные поставщики могли по нажатию кнопки кидать мне на сервер свои товары. У всех разные категории, разные артикулы на одинаковые товары поэтому я немного в замешательстве.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать в какую сторону смотреть?

Заранее спасибо за дельные советы.

Comment: Это непростая задача и она мало имеет отношения к программированию - она скорее про унификацию номенклатуры в рамках одной страны. Подобные вещи несколько лет пытаются внедрить на уровне правительства в рамках электронного документооброта (НДС, электронные счёт-фактуры). Вам можно идти только в сторону жёсткой унификации категорий, артикулов - и всегда быть готовым, что при росте проекта всё сложнее будет поддерживать единообразие, будет всё больше клиентов отваливаться, так слишком много ручного труда по поддержке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить два варианта:

1. Жестко определить формат и структуру документов и принимать от
   поставщиков исключительно в данном формате. Это может быть что
   угодно (xml, json, excel и т.д.), или получение от поставщика ссылки-источника (с данными в формате xml, json) с которого уже по расписанию делать выгрузку.
2. Организовать промежуточный слой хранения данных, в который будут
   сохраняться данные от ваших поставщиков, и уже на своей стороне
   писать разные парсеры для обработки и агрегирования данных от каждого поставщика.